# filter a dataframe based on a if condition applied on a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df and I want to create an if statement to print only specific rows.

```py
pandas_dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'actors' : [['Tom Hanks', 'Tim Allen', 'Don Rickles', 'Jim Varney'],
                                             ['Robin Williams', 'Jonathan Hyde', 'Kirsten Dunst'],
                                             ['Walter Matthau', 'Jack Lemmon', 'Sophia Loren', 'n', 'ix']],
                                 'movie':['Toy Story', 'Jumanji', 'X-men']})
```

I want to print only the row where the list of actors has an actor with length 1, thus I want to print only the third row because it has at least 1 actor with length 1.

```py
+--------------------------------------------------------------+------+
| actors                                                       |movie |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+------
|['Walter Matthau', 'Jack Lemmon', 'Sophia Loren', 'n', 'ix']  | X-men|
+--------------------------------------------------------------+------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
import numpy as np

mask=pandas_dataframe.actors.explode().str.len().eq(1)
res=pandas_dataframe.loc[np.unique(mask.loc[mask].index)]
```

Outputs:

```py
                                              actors  movie
2  [Walter Matthau, Jack Lemmon, Sophia Loren, n,...  X-men
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Very intuitive that you use list and string commands. Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

Use a lambda function and apply:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "actors": [
            ["Tom Hanks", "Tim Allen", "Don Rickles", "Jim Varney"],
            ["Robin Williams", "Jonathan Hyde", "Kirsten Dunst"],
            ["Walter Matthau", "Jack Lemmon", "Sophia Loren", "n", "ix"],
        ],
        "movie": ["Toy Story", "Jumanji", "X-men"],
    }
)

filt = df.actors.apply(lambda x: any(len(y) == 1 for y in x))
df = df[filt]
print(df)
```

Returning:

```
                                              actors   movie
2  [Walter Matthau, Jack Lemmon, Sophia Loren, n, ix]  X-men
```

Comment: My pleasure. Enjoy programming with python

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code, where filter the Dataframe in a single line.

```
df[df.actors.apply(lambda o: any([len(x)==1 for x in o]))]
```